# Does google track my javascript part of website without setting virtual pageviews in google analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, javascript

If I not setting `virtual pageviews` in `google analytics` for my javascript part of website e.g.

`<a href="#" class="slideshow-button clicked">Slideshow</a>`

`<a href="#" class="fullscreen-button clicked">Full Screen</a>`

Google will still track that JS part of website and I will see that in my bounce rate, page per session ... or I need first setting virtual pageviews for google can track that?

Does google track my javascript part of website without setting virtual pageviews in google analytics?

Comment: It looks like you asked the same question in two slightly different ways, so I am closing this one.